# Persistence provider password predicament

Tags: java, hibernate, security, jpa, jdbc

## Background

Plain old Java application, no web servers attached (not even [JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html)), is using JPA to query a database.

## Problem

The JDBC password is exposed in `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql:DATABASE"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="USERNAME"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PASSWORD"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

## Idea

It might be possible to instantiate a [JNDI subcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396052/59087) to set the password within the application's `main` method. This would possibly permit using a JTA data source:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

## Question

How would you externalize the password such that it no longer exists inside `persistence.xml`?

Note: `persistence.xml` is stored in a public repository, so it would be nice if the password wasn't screaming 'please hack me'. Instead, the JDBC connection information should be in a file that doesn't get checked into the repository.

Comment: http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/How-to-encrypt-DB-password-in-persistence-xml-td2868212.html JNDI or pass the password from the app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The password can be externalized by [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1990914/59087) the properties when instantiating the [`EntityManagerFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#createEntityManager-javax.persistence.SynchronizationType-java.util.Map-):

```
  private EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( getPersistenceUnitName(),
      getProperties() );
  }

  private Map getProperties() {
    Map result = new HashMap();

    // Read the properties from a file instead of hard-coding it here.
    // Or pass the password in from the command-line.
    result.put( "javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "PASSWORD" );

    return result;
  }
```